# How does parameters of a method get stored in stack during a recursive call?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, tree

I was doing a leetcode question https://leetcode.com/problems/lowest-common-ancestor-of-a-binary-tree-ii/ and I am confused on how parameters for a method get stored during a recursive call.

If a node gets visited, I wanted to save it's state that it was visited. When I send two variables, when the stack is getting unwinded the updated variable values are being lost.

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */

class Solution {
    public TreeNode lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode root, TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
        boolean val1 = false, val2 = false;
        System.out.println("val1 - "+val1+" val2 - "+val2);
        System.out.println();

        TreeNode node = lca(root, p, q, val1, val2);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("val1 - "+val1+" val2 - "+val2);

        if(val1==true && val2==true)
            return node;
        return null;
    }
    
    private TreeNode lca(TreeNode root, TreeNode p, TreeNode q, boolean val1, boolean val2) {
        if(root==null) 
            return root;
        else if( p==root){
            val1 = true;
            System.out.println("val1 - "+val1+" val2 - "+val2);
            return root;
        } 
        else if( root==q){
            val2 = true;
            System.out.println("val1 - "+val1+" val2 - "+val2);
            return root;
        } 

        TreeNode left = lca(root.left, p, q, val1, val2);
        TreeNode right = lca(root.right, p, q, val1, val2);
        
        if(left==null && right==null) return null;
        else if(left==null) return right;
        else if(right==null) return left;
        else return root;
    }
}

Output -
val1 - false val2 - false

val1 - true val2 - false
val1 - false val2 - true

val1 - false val2 - false
```

But if I send an array and update values inside the array and pass the array itself as a parameter during recursion then the updated variable values are getting persisted.

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */

class Solution {
    public TreeNode lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode root, TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
        boolean res[] = new boolean[2];
        //boolean val1 = false, val2 = false;
        System.out.println("val1 - "+res[0]+" val2 - "+res[1]);
        System.out.println();

        TreeNode node = lca(root, p, q, res);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("val1 - "+res[0]+" val2 - "+res[1]);

        if(res[0]==true && res[1]==true)
            return node;
        return null;
    }
    
    private TreeNode lca(TreeNode root, TreeNode p, TreeNode q, boolean res[]) {
        if(root==null) 
            return root;
        else if( p==root){
            res[0] = true;
            System.out.println("val1 - "+res[0]+" val2 - "+res[1]);
            return root;
        } 
        else if( root==q){
            res[1] = true;
            System.out.println("val1 - "+res[0]+" val2 - "+res[1]);
            return root;
        } 

        TreeNode left = lca(root.left, p, q, res);
        TreeNode right = lca(root.right, p, q, res);
        
        if(left==null && right==null) return null;
        else if(left==null) return right;
        else if(right==null) return left;
        else return root;
    }
}

Output - 

val1 - false val2 - false

val1 - true val2 - false
val1 - true val2 - true

val1 - true val2 - true
```

I feel like I am missing some basic knowledge here, can anyone please help me understand how the two code's are different and any material I can read to improve my knowledge on stack and recursion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has less to do with "recursion" and more to do with the function call itself.

When you're calling `foo(var1, var2)`, the variables get [passed by value](https://icarus.cs.weber.edu/%7Edab/cs1410/textbook/6.Functions/value.html). The changes you make inside the function block aren't propagated outside the function.

When you pass the array, it gets [passed by reference](https://www.cs.fsu.edu/%7Emyers/c++/notes/references.html)/pointer. Any modifications made to it are made to it's actual memory, so the changes gets retained/reflected even outside the function block.

You can read more on the differences between passing by value and reference [here](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/pass-by-value-vs-pass-by-reference).

Edit:
Java is "always" pass-by-value because objects have references which are getting passed by value. This confusing terminology is clarified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523) in detail.

Comment: Which are going to be passed by reference and which will be passed by value in java apart from those two? Any material on that?

Comment: Isn't everything passed by value in java?

Comment: @coder101 clarified that in the edit.